# How do I install open-ssh client and server in an image of type debian:stretch inside a container?

Tags: docker, debian

I need to install ssh in order to run the following command:
`git+ssh://git@github.com/some_org/some_repo#egg=some_egg`

This failed with the following error:

```
Collecting athena from git+ssh://git@github.com/some_org/some_repo-py#egg=some_egg (from -r /requirements/athena.txt (line 2))
  Cloning ssh://git@github.com/some_org/some_repo to /tmp/pip-build-jx3xzcel/athena
error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork
Command "git clone -q ssh://git@github.com/some_org/some_repo /tmp/pip-build-jx3xzcel/athena" failed with error code 128 in None
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r /requirements/athena.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Makefile:109: recipe for target 'build' failed
```

It seems that I do not have the ssh installed in the container, hence, trying to install it.

I have already tried with the commands available on various pages to install ssh on Debian, none of them have worked. Those commands include installing `openssh-server` and `openssh-client` via `apt-get`

```
RUN      apt-get install -yqq openssh-server
```

I expect to have ssh installed and this step in the dockerfile to be a successful one but instead, I am getting the following error:

```
Step 20/38 : RUN      apt-get install openssh-server
 ---> Running in e63d8d044b88
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package openssh-server
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install openssh-server' returned a non-zero code: 100
make: *** [dev] Error 100
```

Comment: are you doing the apt-get update before running apt-get install? seems like its not able to locate the package either try apt-get update before this or try adding ppa for it

Comment: Can you post your full dockerfile ?